# selenium testing on website content based on the unformatted content as the expected value

Tags: html, selenium

I am able to successfully test the content in a website where the content does not have any html element formatting such as `<b>`, `<i>`, `<sup>`, etc. This is easy. I just use `String.equals("expectedContent")`. However, when there is an html element involved in the middle such as `<br>` or `<p>`, the test fails because that is not included in the unformatted expected content. Is there a way for Selenium to ignore those html elements so I can compare apples to apples?

here is the sample html:

```
<p><strong>Paragraph-a.</strong></p>
<div>
<p>paragraph-b.</p><p>paragraph-c.</p>
</div>
```

my test content is: Paragraph-a. paragraph-b. paragraph-c.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you post some HTML for us to look at?

Comment: hi Richard...i've added the html in my post..hope you can help me..tnx

Comment: You can edit your post and add it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following results are based off the HTML in the question, slightly modified to include a `<br>` tag in the first paragraph.

```
<html><body>
<p><strong>Para<br>graph-a.</strong></p>
<div>
<p>paragraph-b.</p><p>paragraph-c.</p>
</div>
</body></html>
```

The Python 2.7.6 code I'm using is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("file:///C:\testing\\test.html")
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body")
print element.text
browser.close()
```

The simple XPath `/html/body` retrieves the elements without any of the tags.

```
Para
graph-a.
paragraph-b.
paragraph-c.
```

I can drill down to the contents of the first paragraph using `/html/body/p/strong`.

```
Para
graph-a.
```

Can you tell what I think the problem is yet? Tags disappear in the sense that it's not outputting the `<strong>`, but the `<br>` tag translates into a newline. Let's add a few lines of code to the Python script, just before the browser close:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("file:///C:\testing\\test.html")
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/p/strong")
print element.text
print text == "Paragraph-a."
print text == "Para<br>graph-a."
print text == "Para\ngraph-a."
browser.close()
```

This script outputs the following:

```
Para
graph-a.
False
False
True
```

The conclusion is that while we can ignore most HTML tags, we need to be careful when comparing against elements that include line breaks.

Comment: thanks Tetrinity. I will try this out. Appreciate very much your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the given below scripting

```
int no_of_paragraphs = driver.findElements(By.tagName("p")).size();

for(int i=1;i<=no_of_paragraphs;i++)

{

   System.out.print(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p:nth-of-type("+i+")")).getText() + "\t");

}
```